# Laravel using non-existent DB settings and failing with PDOException (1045). How? Why?

Tags: laravel, pdo, eloquent

I'm starting a aravel4 project which needs to connect to a pre-existing database.
I've set my env like `'local' => array('*.dev')`, and am hitting the project via http://my.project.dev/products.

My `app/config/database.php` is intentionally incomplete, and looks **exactly** like this:

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mysql',
        'host'     => '192.168.1.250',
        'database' => '',
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'   => 'm3_',
    ),
```

My `app/config/local/database.php` looks like this:

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mysql',
        'host'     => '192.168.1.250',
        'database' => 'realDbName',
        'username' => 'realUserName',
        'password' => 'realPass',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'   => 'm3sandbox_',
    ),
```

Yet, an error is being thrown saying that the application is trying to connect to ***my*** outward facing IP (not even the `localhost` loopback) with the `www-data` user:

> PDOException (1045)
>   SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'www-data'@'192.168.1.175' (using password: NO)

I am completely boggled.
What default is it trying to use, and where the heck is that getting that from?
More importantly, how do I correct this?

Comment: It's not trying to connect to your outward facing IP. The error message is saying the user 'www-data' on the **host** 192.168.1.175.
I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the environment detection.
Could you please post the output of [`gethostname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out the answer was Environments.
Seems weird that the fallback was to thrown an exception referring to `'www-data'@'192.168.1.175'`,  but alas, the problem was triggered by the empty credentials in my `app/config/database.php` and a misconfigured local environment attribute.

In case it helps someone else, remember, the environments are matching MACHINE NAMES.
For some reason, I had it in my head that it was pattern matching against the URL requested :|

Comment: Knew it was something like that ;)